# sum of n 5-sided biased dice

Tags: probability

We consider n die whose faces are numbered from 1 to 5. If those dice are fair, the probability that a certain sum, denoted by p, of the n dice sides to occur is defined by 
[P(p,n,s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYJjw.png)

Now, if we assume that all the sides of the dice have the same probability to occur which is 25/124 except the face number 3 which have a probability 24/124. We verify that the sum of probabilities is (25*4+24)/124 is equal to 1. What becomes the formula above in this case?

Comment: What are the meanings of $k$ and  $k_{max}$ ?

Comment: kmax = floor((p-n)/s) or simply the result of the euclidean division of (p-n) by s

Comment: And what is the meaning of k ?

Comment: it's simply a sum index which takes the values between 0 and kmax. for example for n = 2, s = 5 and 2 <= p < 7, k can be just 0, and for 7<= p <= 10, k can be 0 or 1

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dice.html

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, i found the solution alone
[P(p,n,s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K3NH.png) where s²/(s^3-1) = 25/124 and (s²-1)/(s^3-1) = 24/124
here the plot for n = 2
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWAC9.png)